# Tkinter - how do I teleport mouse pointer

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, cross-platform, mouse

I am making a graphics editor in Python/Tkinter, and I want to accomplish 2 things:

1. Detect mouse movement without actually moving the pointer. I figured that every time I get a 'mouse moved' event I would calculate the delta of the pointer and then snap it back to previous position.
2. Loop the pointer around the screen edges.

Is there a way to set the position of the mouse pointer? I am making it in Linux but ideally it should be cross-platform.

Comment: "detect mouse movement without actually moving the pointer" doesn't seem to make sense. If the pointer doesn't move, there's no movement to detect.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley When you play a video game, the pointer is locked to the center of the screen but you still detect mouse movement.